# jQuery toggle functions only assign a css to an element for a second (then removes it)?

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
   <div class="user-contribution">
     <p class="user-review"> Review</p> 2. Animate this
     <a class="user-review-toggle" href="#">Read more...</a> // 1. Clicking this
```

this CSS:

```
            .user-contribution {
                overflow: hidden;
                img {
                    float: left;
                    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }
                .user-review {
                    font-size: 12px;
                    line-height: 14px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }
```

and this JS:

```
            $(".user-review-toggle").toggle(function(){
                $(this).css("backgroundPosition", "0 -12px");
                $(this).prev('.user-review').animate({height:150},200);
                $(this).prev('.user-review').css("overflow", "visible");
            },function(){
                $(this).css("backgroundPosition", "0 0");
                $(this).prev('.user-review').animate({height:98},200);
                $(this).prev('.user-review').css("overflow", "hidden");
            });
```

For some reason, when I click the `.user-review-toggle` link the `overflow: visible` is only applied to the `user-review` div for a seconds then it returns to hidden (I should  stay visible).

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't exactly see why, but if you apply the overflow changes in the `oncomplete`-callback of the animation it works. At least, if I understood your problem.

```
$(".user-review-toggle").toggle(function(){
  $(this).css("backgroundPosition", "0 -12px");
  $(this).prev('.user-review').animate({height: 150}, 200, function () {
    $(this).css("overflow", "visible");
  });
}, function(){
  $(this).css("backgroundPosition", "0 0");
  $(this).prev('.user-review').animate({height: 98}, 200, function () {
    $(this).css("overflow", "hidden");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rWTXe/

Comment: Hey it worked. So basically you turned the `$(this).css("overflow", "visible");` into a callback? (sorry, until today I'm not sure what a callback is).

Comment: @alexchenco A callback is just an every day function. Only that it is called at a defined time. For example when an animation finishes or an ajax call succeeds or fails. You can't exactly force a callback to work. It's allways the API you use, which has to accept and call the given callback.